Failed to connect to Azure SQL server from android due to TLS version mismatch using jtds connection
I also tried added ssl=require in connection string it returned error as "Network error IOException: SSL handshake aborted..."
if I added sslProtocol=TLSv1.1 since in Azure server it set as 1.0, but it return message as "Reason:Login failed due to client TLS version being less than server.."
It is Using jtds.-1.3.1.jar
or what is the right way to set TLS version in connection string?

Just making sure you've seen JDBC vs Web Service for Android

oh you mean the safest way is using Web Service

Safest and less likely to have strange networking problems when you try to demo your app over the public internet.


Login failed due to client TLS version being less than server

According to this

customers who are using a TLS version lower than the minimum TLS version of the server will fail to authenticate.

That may be the reason to get the above error. So, go to  Networking tab of azure SQL server, go to Connectivity option, select required TLS version in your case it is 1.1 and click on save to save the changes as shown below:

After selecting correct version of TLS you will be able to connect to SQL server successfully without any error. For more information you can refer to the related SO thread.

actually the Azure Server already set to TLS 1.0 and in connection string i did to set sslProtocol=TLSv1 and to TLSV1.1 too but the message remain the same .

and one more thing im afraid to change setting on Azure as some of database is used by client already. this one using windows connection no issue, but above one using android connection string
